# Proving a definition and the general term for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Consider the sequence $(T_n) = 1, 4, 9, 16 ...$

In and exercise I'm trying to solve I'm asked to:

> A) Show that $(T_n)$ is defined by $T_n=1+3+5+7+...+2n-1$
>
> B) Prove that the general term for $T_n$ is $n^2$

Assuming the A) is true, I can set $1+3+5+7+...+2n-1=n^2$ , and then prove by induction that $(T_n)$ is indeed of general term $n^2$.

But how can I prove A)?

Edit: What other ways are there to prove this?

Comment: It looks like you are _defining_ $T_n$ to have property (b) and so there is nothing to prove in part (b).  Or, you are _defining_ $T_n$ to have property (a).  Either way, you cannot prove a definition.

Comment: Right, seems redundant, but that's just the way the exercise is formulated. First I'm supposed to solve A) and and then B). Assuming B) was not obvious, how would you prove A)?

Comment: In fact, neither of the statements that have to be proven are obvious. We have to assume one of the two.

Comment: The exercise is ill-formulated. If $T_n={1,4,9,16,...}$ is the definition, then it can well be $T_N=\{1,4,9,16,9,4,1,4,9,16,9,4,1,...($repeat the pattern$)\}$ and can also be any other thing.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to determine the sum : $$S=1+3+5+\cdots (2n-1)$$

Write the sum in reverse $$S=(2n-1)+\cdots +5+3+1$$

Now, you see by adding the columns that $$2S=2n\cdot n$$ holds, which immediately gives $S=n^2$

Comment: Why does looking at the columns produce $2S=2n*n$? What is producing this equality?

Comment: $1$ and $2n-1$ sum up to $2n$ , also $3$ and $2n-3$ and so on. We have $n$ columns.

Comment: I see, so $S=2n*\frac{n}{2}$ because you take exactly half of the elements in the sum when you form $2n$. You then multiply that by $2$.